# How do I shorten an array in Matlab to prevent a dimension mismatch?

Tags: arrays, matlab

I'm taking in two arrays and comparing them. However, one array might be larger than the other.

So, how can I trim the larger array to the size of the smaller one to prevent a dimension mismatch?

Now, I'm using this code to trim the rows:

[nRows1, nCols1] = size(data1);

[nRows2, nCols2] = size(data2);

data1(nRows1 + 1:nRows2, :) = [];

But, this is still not working and it says that there is a dimension mismatch.

Comment: You forgot to index (all) columns: `data1(nRows1:nRows2,:) = []`. And you probably need a `+1`: `data1(nRows1+1:nRows2,:) = []`

Comment: Oh, thanks I forgot about that.

Comment: My Data did not become formatted strangely anymore, but for some reason the array is not being trimmed.

Comment: Are you sure `nRows2` exceeds `nRows1`?

Comment: Oh, sorry, my mistake.

Comment: Thank you, it's working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
data1(size(data2, 1)+1:end, :) = [];
data2(size(data1, 1)+1:end, :) = [];
```